# Imprimir miembros de un objeto a través de un bucle ForEach

Tags: c++

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo la clase se arriba tiene un miembro uint16_ edad;
la pregunta seria como hago para que en un bucle for each a través de un contenedor que contiene varias clases idol y que en el bucle for each imprima este miembro edad

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el contenedor declarado con vector

```
for(auto &x : personas){
     std::cout << x._edad << std::endl;
}
```

Este seria mas o menos como seria
pero me da error, quiero saber si se puede hacer esto con un bucle for each

Comment: Si usas `auto` el compilador infiere el tipo. Por lo tanto no debes indicar si se trata de un puntero, un valor o una referencia.

Comment: No puede darte error, he hecho el mismo programa que tú [y funciona perfectamente](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hCuNNQwKlBu2kpYc).

Comment: @Mateo Si no indicas que es una referencia, el compilador entenderá que lo quieres por copia, lo que no siempre es buena idea.

Comment: A primera vista no parece haber nada malo, y PaperBirdMaster tiene un link donde el código que colocas funciona. Dices "*pero me da error*", que error te da?

Comment: @Pablochaches lo que pasa es que me equivoque en la pregunta , en la declaracion de objetos con vector yo los declaraba de esta forma personas[0]_edad = 21; personas[1]_edad = 22; etc pero al momento de imprimir en el bucle for each daba error no imprimia nada, pero de esta forma funciona std::vector<pers> personas = {2,8,21}; no se porque funciona de esta manera y de la otra manera no

Comment: Y como se suponía que íbamos a saber eso? Comparte el código que te da problema, así te podemos responder